Regarding buying a train ticket from Friedrichstadt in Germany to Toender in Denmark
Can I buy a ticket at Friedrichstadt Station to Toender in Denmark because I can't do it in the DB Navigator app?

Friedrichstadt - Toender st - Outbound journey

When are you trying to buy it for? What precisely is failing? Also there seem to be multiple Friedrichstadts, so check you have the right one, Schleswig-Holstein or North Rhine-Westphalia.


I can't do it in the DB Navigator app?

Why not? It's easily available on the bahn.de website. Trains go once an hour.


... and in the app, I am offered tons of possible tickets. OP, why do you think you can't buy a ticket in the app?

He might have disabled using buses

@8192K: It's a train replacement bus (they are working on two bridges), so it counts as a train.

If you disable going by bus, this will not show.

DB shows the NAH.SH logo instead of a price, because this journey is not covered by a DB tariff.
There is still a WEITER / CONTINUE / SELECT button, where they give you all the options of the NAH.SH transport association. You can buy the ticket directly from DB.
This is slightly confusing, as not displaying a price often means that they cannot sell a ticket for the connection. Then, the button is missing, too.
